# I can not see logs in DbgView, but the filter can be seen in DeviceTree

Tags: c, windows, driver, minifilter

I want write minifilter driver for file system, I compiled the code in .sys file(
there are no errors), but after install, I can not see logs in DbgView. But the filter can be seen in DeviceTree program. Please tell me what my problem. Thanks.

```
#pragma once
#include <FltKernel.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ntstrsafe.h>
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PostFileOperationCallback ( IN OUT PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, 
                                                      IN PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
                                                      IN PVOID CompletionContext, 
                                                      IN FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags);

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
    PreFileOperationCallback (
    __inout PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    __in PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    __deref_out_opt PVOID *CompletionContext
    );

NTSTATUS FilterUnload ( IN FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags );

NTSTATUS FilterLoad (IN PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS  FltObjects,
                     IN FLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_FLAGS  Flags,
                     IN DEVICE_TYPE  VolumeDeviceType,
                     IN FLT_FILESYSTEM_TYPE  VolumeFilesystemType);


typedef struct _MINIFILTER
{
    PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject;
    PFLT_FILTER pFilter;
} MINIFILTER, *PMINIFILTER;


const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {

    { IRP_MJ_CREATE,                                
    0,                                          
    PreFileOperationCallback,
    PostFileOperationCallback },

    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

const FLT_CONTEXT_REGISTRATION Contexts[] = {
    { FLT_CONTEXT_END }
};

CONST FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {

    sizeof( FLT_REGISTRATION ),         //  Size
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,           //  Version
    0,                                  //  Flags

    Contexts,                               //  Context
    Callbacks,                          //  Operation callbacks

    FilterUnload,                     //  FilterUnload

    FilterLoad,                    //  InstanceSetup
    NULL,            //  InstanceQueryTeardown
    NULL,            //  InstanceTeardownStart
    NULL,         //  InstanceTeardownComplete

    NULL,                 //  GenerateFileName
    NULL            //  NormalizeNameComponent
};

MINIFILTER fileManager;

NTSTATUS FilterLoad (IN PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS  FltObjects,
                     IN FLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_FLAGS  Flags,
                     IN DEVICE_TYPE  VolumeDeviceType,
                     IN FLT_FILESYSTEM_TYPE  VolumeFilesystemType)
{
    DbgPrint("12313");
    if (VolumeDeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_NETWORK_FILE_SYSTEM) {
        return STATUS_FLT_DO_NOT_ATTACH;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS FilterUnload ( IN FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags )
{
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
    PreFileOperationCallback (
    __inout PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    __in PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    __deref_out_opt PVOID *CompletionContext
    )
{

    NTSTATUS status;
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject;


    FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS returnStatus = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;

    /* If this is a callback for a FS Filter driver then we ignore the event */
    if(FLT_IS_FS_FILTER_OPERATION(Data))
    {
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    if (FltObjects->FileObject != NULL && Data != NULL) {
        FileObject = Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject;
        if(FileObject != NULL && Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE)
        {
            DbgPrint("MiniFilter: YES!!!");
        }
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PostFileOperationCallback ( IN OUT PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, 
                                                      IN PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
                                                      IN PVOID CompletionContext, 
                                                      IN FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags)
{

    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/* 
* обработчик-заглушка 
*/
NTSTATUS
    OnStubDispatch(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    IN PIRP           Irp
    )
{
    Irp->IoStatus.Status      = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest (Irp,
        IO_NO_INCREMENT
        );
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}


VOID OnUnload( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject )
{
    FltUnregisterFilter(fileManager.pFilter);
    DbgPrint("MiniFilter: Unloaded");
}



NTSTATUS DriverEntry( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath )
{
    int i;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PCHAR ConfigInfo;
    UNICODE_STRING test;

    DbgPrint("MiniFilter: Started.");

    // Register a dispatch function
    for (i = 0; i < IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; i++) 
    {
        theDriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = OnStubDispatch;
    }

    theDriverObject->DriverUnload  = OnUnload; 

    fileManager.pDriverObject = theDriverObject;

    status = FltRegisterFilter(theDriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &fileManager.pFilter);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("MiniFilter:  Driver not started. ERROR FltRegisterFilter - %08x\n", status); 
        return status;
    }

    status = FltStartFiltering( fileManager.pFilter );

    if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) {
        FltUnregisterFilter( fileManager.pFilter );
        DbgPrint("MiniFilter:  Driver not started. ERROR FltStartFiltering - %08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    DbgPrint("MiniFilter: Filter was started and configured.");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
status = FltEnumerateVolumes(fileManager.pFilter, NULL, 0, &NumberofVolumes);
buffer = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool,1024);

if(buffer != NULL)
{
  for(i = 0; i < NumberofVolumes; i++)
  {
    status = FltEnumerateVolumeInformation(fileManager.pFilter, i, FilterVolumeBasicInformation, buffer, 1024, &NumberofVolumes2);
    pFilterInfo = (PFILTER_VOLUME_BASIC_INFORMATION)buffer;             
    uStrVolume.Length = (USHORT)pFilterInfo->FilterVolumeNameLength;
    uStrVolume.MaximumLength = uStrVolume.Length;
    uStrVolume.Buffer = &pFilterInfo->FilterVolumeName[0];

    if(NT_SUCCESS(status)){
      status = FltGetVolumeFromName(fileManager.pFilter, &uStrVolume, &pFLTVolume);
      if(NT_SUCCESS(status)){
        status = FltAttachVolume(fileManager.pFilter, pFLTVolume, NULL, NULL);
        DbgPrint("Attached Volume Successfully.................... \n");    
        FltObjectDereference(pFLTVolume);               
      }             
    }
  }         
  ExFreePool(buffer);   
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the missing fragment, but there's something desperately wrong with it. Still trying to work it out. Bluescreen near FltGetVolumeFromName, location discovered by bisection.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Vista debug messages are filtred out. You must apply mask to be able to see this messages on DbgView or Windbg. Just read this article http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=295 or you can fix it from windbg:
ed nt!Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (for x64)